# Cannot skip from an action to a Jsp with Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I make 2 actions, action1 is aimed to update some info, action2 is to retrieve it. Often, I use action2 to search and a JSP to display. Now there is something more, after seeing the JSP, firstly enter action1 to modify something, then goto action2 to retrieve, finally skip to the Jsp to display the info. I use Struts2 to achieve it. But in fact the info is not changed, I need to refresh the webpage so that it can be displayed normally. At first I guess it's cache who leads to this condition. So I add some tags in JSP to avoid this and rewrite the url using ?time=${time}, but still in vain. My code is as follows.

MessageAction.java:

```
    public String getMessage() throws Exception{
        Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();      
        Account account = (Account)(session.get("account"));
        List<Message> messages = messageBo.getMessageByAccount(account);
        session.remove("messages");
        session.put("messages", messages);
        time = Long.toHexString(new Date().getTime());
        System.out.println(time);
        return SUCCESS;

    }

    @Action(value="modifyMessage",
            results={
            @Result(name="success",location="/getMessage.action",type="redirectAction")})
    public String modifyMessage() throws Exception{ 
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();             
        String field = request.getParameter("field");
        String value = request.getParameter("value");
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));      
        messageBo.updateMessageByField(id, field, value);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

struts.xml:

```
    <action name="getMessage" class="com.ailonger.action.MessageAction" method="getMessage">  
        <result type="redirect">/room/my_message.jsp?time=${time}</result>  
    </action>
```

How to skip to JSP directly after entering action2?

Comment: Why do you mix annotations with actions in struts.xml? What is `messageBo.updateMessageByField(id, field, value);` doing? Post your jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never redirect to JSP from the action. The code below is `redirect` result type that loose any request attributes and `valueStack` from the previous action, so the  jsp view becomes without model. The new action context is created for the new request which is result of redirection to the jsp.

```
<action name="getMessage" class="com.ailonger.action.MessageAction" method="getMessage">  
    <result type="redirect">/room/my_message.jsp?time=${time}</result>  
</action>
```

The code should change to use `dispatcher` result type that is default and could be omitted in xml configuration.

```
<action name="getMessage" class="com.ailonger.action.MessageAction" method="getMessage">  
    <result>/room/my_message.jsp?time=${time}</result>  
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement.. If you are trying to forward a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file),then use

```
forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
```

Comment: For example, I log in my website, I have to pass through action2 to get info and bring it to the Jsp, so I can see the info. Now after I see I want to update some info, (in the Jsp there is the update function). But when I updated in MySQL, the Jsp doesn't refresh and the url isn't changed, although I rewrite it by ?time=${time}.

Comment: update your form bean with the updated values in the action before you call jsp.